# Deplete set value every X second in Update method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to **deplete** value of health from set value every 1 second in Update method. I wrote the code, but it seems like it depletes faster than 1 second.

In an Update method, I call:

```
if (Hunger <= 0.0f)
{
    userHealth -= HealthDepletionValue * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Which should deplete set value of **HealthDepletionValue** every second **Time.deltaTime**.

When I run the game, it depletes **HealthDepletionValue** every 0.1 second or something along those lines. But surely not every 1 second, like I want to.

Did I miss something?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. For example, showing the values and types of `userHealth` and the other variables.

Comment: @mjwills lets say <code>userHealth</code> value is 1. But I'm debugging the issue and it appears that <b>Time.deltaTime</b> returns value between 0.1 and 0.3. This kind of makes sense why it doesn't work for me now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/122349/how-to-run-update-every-second.html), Update() runs once per frame. So if you're game is running 30 frames/second, then Update() will execute 30 times/second.

To specify a function to be executed every x seconds, you can use [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). To do this, put the logic you want executed every second into it's own method:

```
void DepleteHealth()
{
    if (Hunger <= 0.0f)
    {
        userHealth -= HealthDepletionValue * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

And then in the `Start()` method, call `InvokeRepeating`, passing in your method name and the number of seconds between execution of said method:

```
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("DepleteHealth", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

---

The post above also shows alternative ways to handle this. Including tracking a second counter within the Update() method, to ensure that you're logic is only executed if the counter has passed a full second.

Comment: How could I deplete it every 1 second, if bool is set to true? Using InvokeRepeating.

Comment: @ArthurBelkin See updated answer with an example of how that would be done

Comment: thanks mate, that worked. For some reason, if I had InvokeRepeating at the end of the Start method, it did not work. Would you happen to know why? because it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to InvokeRepeating would be to create your own timer.

```
float timer = 0;

Update()
{
  if (Hunger <= 0.0f)
  {
    timer += time.deltaTime;
    if (timer > 1f){
        userHealth -= HealthDepletionValue;
        timer = 0; //reset timer
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and the [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) class.

```
public void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(DepleteHealth(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5));
}

public IEnumerator DepleteHealth (TimeSpan frequency, int loss) {
   var wait = new WaitForSeconds((float)frequency.TotalSeconds());
   while(true) {
        userHealth -= loss;
        yield return wait;
   }
}
```

This can be [stopped](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html) and [started](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) pretty easily.